# Blocking every URL with "?" in it

Tags: robots.txt, query-string

Will below `Disallow` function will block every URL which has "?" in it?

```
Disallow: /*?*PrintPage=yes*
```

I was actually checking few pages with "?" in them and they were not indexed in Google and then I saw some other URLs with "?" and they are indexed in Google.

Why is this happening, also these "?" pages don't have `noindex` tag or `canonical` tag.

Comment: @unor you have edited OP robots.txt by mistake I think, but my answer is based on original post. Hope it's fine.

Comment: @Goyllo: Ah, didn’t notice this (I didn’t add the `*`, but made them visible with the code markup). But I assume that OP actually intended to use the three `*` characters there, instead of using the italics formatting (for example, so that "PrintPage" doesn’t have to be the first parameter in the query component).

Comment: Yeah got you after I click on edit option. It was not visible due to bad code markup, thank you @unor

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not block all webpages that have `?` in URL.

```
Disallow: /*?*PrintPage=yes*
```

This will block below kind of pages for example.

```
www.example.com/sometext?xPrintPage=yes.html
www.example.com/123?PrintPage=yes.php
www.example.com/Some-123?xyz-PrintPage=yes/another-page/
```

Did you notice anything? That rule will block only those pages that contain `?` and `PrintPage=yes`, In that rule, you can add any characters before and after `?` . Same thing will apply to `*PrintPage=yes*` as well.

To block every webpage that have `?` in URL, you have to use `*` in both front and end side like this

```
Disallow: /*?*
```

I strongly recommended you to checkout this [Google reference about robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values).

Comment: Thanks Goyllo for the answer, I was thinking same that it should not block all the URLs with "? " but then when I couldn't find those URLs in Google index I got confused. Anyways thanks for clearing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block pages with parameters the best way to do it is with Google search console under Crawl > URL Parameters. This will remove the pages pretty quickly and will likely improve your overall rankings.

Comment: Thanks Roie Speiser for the reply, yes I intend to do that.